# Do +1/+1 counters go away with -1/-1 counters?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

with one of the main mechanics of Amonkhet being -1/-1 counters, i am worried about how that will affect my +1/+1 counter deck, specifically [Gleam of Authority](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGleam%20of%20Authority%5d). if a +1/+1 counter cancels out a -1/-1 counter, will it go away if a creature has both, rendering my creature with [Gleam of Authority](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGleam%20of%20Authority%5d) less powerful?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, +1/+1 counters and -1/-1 counters will cancel each other other. This is done as as state-based action, any time a player is about to receive priority.

> 704.1. State-based actions are game actions that happen automatically whenever certain conditions (listed below) are met. State-based actions don’t use the stack.
>
> 704.5. The state-based actions are as follows:
>
> > 704.5r If a permanent has both a +1/+1 counter and a -1/-1 counter on it, N +1/+1 and N -1/-1 counters are removed from it, where N is the smaller of the number of +1/+1 and -1/-1 counters on it.

Comment: (I didn't notice the duplicate until after I answered).